# Bash shell in one of Eclipse's windows

Tags: linux, eclipse, bash

I use Eclipse under a Linux machine (Ubuntu) and I usually have to use the shell a lot when I program - e.g., to use source control, perform builds. Is there a way to make gnome-terminal (or any other bash terminal for that matter) part of the eclipse views, so I can dock it where ever I want in the Eclipse work area?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an integrated terminal use: http://elt.googlecode.com